# How can i redirect to anthoer website when i use base tag?

Tags: html, redirect, base-tag

I am using base tag to keep CSS and JAVASCRIPT when any one doing trailing slash, or write any thing after last slash in url ?

for example my website like this:

```
http://www.example.com
```

because i am using base tag so when i redirect any thing its be like this:

```
http://www.example.com/anything
```

when i  redirect to another website like facebook
so its be like this

```
http://www.example.com/https://www.facebook.com
```

i want be like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com
```

this is my base tag

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

how can i do this ?
any help i will be gratefull

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of my question and i want share it with you because you deserve it, it's so simple just put two slash before the URL.

like this:

```
<a href = "//https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
```

and it works perfectly 
thank for every one see my question.